# Combine interceptor validation and controller validation in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I need solution for how to combine interceptor validation and controller validation with Spring so I can display all errors(come from interceptor and controller) in the page.

My current scenario:
When interceptor fetch error he redirect to the current page and display the error without going to the controller.

I need to go to controller also to do the other validation and take with me interceptor errors if exist because I need user to know all errors in the page.

Can I pass attributes from interceptor to controller or what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the validation errors from the interceptor to the controller via a request attribute:

```
public class FooInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        request.setAttribute("interceptorValidationErrors", "a list of validation errors");

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

And read them in the controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    String get(HttpServletRequest request) {

        List<ObjectError> interceptorErrors = (List<ObjectError>) request.getAttribute("interceptorValidationErrors");

        return "someViewName";
    }
}
```

Comment: Give me null pointer exception when try to access the attribute in the controller by(request.getAttribute("interceptorValidationErrors"), request object is filled but haven't interceptorValidationErrors attribute.

Comment: @MohammedMostafa is your interceptor actually being called? you need to configure it with spring

Comment: You are right it is called but wasn't reach to request.setattribute, When I change interceptor from extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter to implements HandlerInterceptor its worked fine(I don't know why!)